# Given $X,Y$ are independent Poisson random variables. Distribution of $Y-X$?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

Say,$X$~$Pois(\lambda_1)$ and $Y$~$Pois(\lambda_2)$.

Let $Z=Y-X$.

So, $P(Z=z)=P(Y-X=z)=P(Y=z+X)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}P(Y=z+x)P(X=x)$.

(Last step, because of independence of ($X,Y$) ).

Thus, $P(Z=z)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}P(Y=z+x)P(X=x)=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\lambda_2)^{z+x}}{(z+x)!}e^{-\lambda_2}\dfrac{(\lambda_1)^x}{x!}e^{-\lambda_1}=e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}(\lambda_2)^z\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(\lambda_2)^{x}}{(z+x)!}\dfrac{(\lambda_1)^x}{x!}=e^{-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)}(\lambda_2)^z\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(z+x)!}\dfrac{(\lambda_1\lambda_2)^x}{x!}$

I am kinda stuck here, I can't think of any such discrete distribution which takes a form similar to this, the solution to this question gives a hint about the $Bessel's$ function, but I don't know how to tackle this. Can anyone help ?

Comment: This distribution is known under the name of [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution)

Comment: You need to use the definition of the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1), $I_\alpha(u) = \sum _{m=0}^{\infty }{\frac {1}{m!\,\Gamma (m+\alpha +1)}}\left({\frac {u}{2}}\right)^{2m+\alpha }$ (set $x=m$,$z=\alpha$ there's a small manipulation required to see what $u$ here should be); there's an outline of what you're trying to do on the Wikipedia page for this distribution that Yves linked that should let you see to pull out a term in the ratio of $\lambda$s to a particular power from the sum.